Error en el metodo de pago Stripe con django
Estoy trabajando en mi proyecto de django, mi proyecto trata de una pagina de entrenamiento online donde los usuarios pueden pagar una suscripción por ver una serie de rutina, para el método de pago le implemente stripe, lo configure en mi proyecto e hice las pruebas y todo fue un éxito pero el error que me da es cuando trato de guardar en mi base de datos la suscripción junto con el usuario que la esta pagando, ya que el sistema detecta que el usuario no esta logeado, esto se debe a que cuando el usuario le da al botón de suscribirme automáticamente lo redirige en la misma ventana a la pagina de stripe y que cuando registra los datos de la tarjeta y le da pagar, y le dice pago exitoso automáticamente lo redirige a pantalla de suscess.html donde tengo la rutina para que guarde automáticamente los datos del usuario en la base de datos, una solución que me plantee fue que cuando el usuario le de al boton de suscribirme se abra una ventana nueva del producto que esta en stripe para asi dejar la ventana de mi proyecto abierta y mi sistema detecte que el usuario esta logeado.
models.py
class Product(models.Model):  
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
   description = models.TextField()  
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  
   stripe_product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)  

view.py
 class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):  
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  

      id = request.POST.get('precio_id')   
      try:  
        producto = Product.objects.get(id=id)  # Cambié nombre de variable a 'producto'  
        
        # Guarda el precio_id en la sesión  
        request.session['precio_id'] = producto.stripe_product_id  
        
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(  
            payment_method_types=['card'],   
            line_items=[{  
                'price': producto.stripe_product_id,  
                'quantity': 1,  
            }],  
            mode='payment',  
            success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',  
            cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/cancel.html',  
        )  

        return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)  
    
      except Product.DoesNotExist:  
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("El producto no existe.")  
      except Exception as e:  
        return JsonResponse({"error": str(e)}, status=500)

pantalla.html
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>  
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand">
       <img alt="Brand Logo" height="50" src="{% static 'images/logo_white.png'%}" width="50"/>
    </div>
    <div class="special-offer">
        INITIALIZATION TRAINING WITH
    </div>
    <div class="black-friday">
        Ma’am! Yes Ma’am!
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
    </div>
    <div class="price-tag">
        ONLY $125
    </div>
    
    <button class="shop-now" data-precio-id="1">SUSCRIBIME</button>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img alt="Person training" height="700" src="{% static 'images/imagen_prueba.png' %}" width="300"/>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>+12 345 578 901
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-globe"></i>www.website.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

script
 <script>  
    $('.shop-now').click(function() {  
        const precioId = $(this).data('precio-id');  
        
        $.ajax({  
            url: '/suscribirse/',  // Tu endpoint en Django  
            type: 'POST',  
            data: {  
                'precio_id': precioId,  
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',  // Token CSRF para Django  
            },  
            success: function(data) {  
                if (data.id) {  
                    // Redirigir a la URL de la sesión en Stripe  
                    window.location.href = `https://checkout.stripe.com/session/${data.id}`;  
                } else {  
                    alert('Error: No se ha recibido un ID de sesión');  
                }  
            },  
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {  
                console.error('Error:', error);  // Agregar información extra en la consola  
                alert('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + xhr.responseText);  
            } 
        });  
    });
</script>

ese codigo de javascript es el que manda la informacion osea la id de mi producto a la view.py e abrir la ventana nueva de stripe para pagar la suscripcion, pero cuando le doy a al boton de suscribirme me sale un mensaje en el navegador: "Ha ocurrido un error: undefined"

El mensaje, es el alert que mandas? donde está el error que mostraría el console ? Prueba con alert('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + (xhr.responseJSON?.error)); a cambio,

Por favor, agrega esta información, completa, en la publicación.

hice una modificaciones, y ahora me abre una ventana de stripe pero me sale este error en la pagina: Something went wrong The page you were looking for could not be found. Please check the URL or contact the merchant. yo creo que es la url que estoy generando con el script que no me redirige bien. esta fue la modificacion que le hice al script **window.open(https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/${data.id}, '_blank'); **

Ronald, ve agregando estos cambios en la publicacion, se puede editar
